# How can I write a python selenium webscraping script using chromedriver on github codespaces?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, codespaces

I have got github codespaces environment and I have installed both selenium and the necessary chromedriver-binary using pip

`pip install selenium chromedriver-binary`

Here's an example of the Python web scraper I'm writing

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

class PriceScraper:

    def scrape(self):

        input_url = "https://www.google.com"
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        service = Service('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
        driver.get(input_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = PriceScraper()
    scraper.scrape()
```

I have installed all the necessary pip packages and I have confirmed the installation of the chromium and the chromedriver by running:

```
(venv) $   sudo apt-get install -y chromium-browser chromium-chromedriver python3-selenium
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-selenium is already the newest version (4.0.0~a1+dfsg1-1.1).
chromium-browser is already the newest version (1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.3).
chromium-chromedriver is already the newest version (1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.3).
```

And checking by running
`ls -l /usr/bin/chromedriver`

But when I try to execute the python from my vscode codespaces terminal as follows:

`python3 scrape_prices.py`

It returns the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Interestingly when I try to run chromedriver from the command line it says:

```
Command '/usr/bin/chromedriver' requires the chromium snap to be installed.
Please install it with:

snap install chromium
```

And when I attempt to install `snap` with `snap install chromium`

I get the following error

```
error: cannot communicate with the server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/chromium: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

I'm unsure how to get this working

Comment: you haven't installed chrome yet, in order to use selenium you need to install chrome browser too

Comment: I have amended the question to add that I had installed both chromium and the driver - see notes above.

Comment: the best way will be to use a portable version of chromium, download portable chromium attach it to the script and modify `options` parameter

Comment: another way can be by using docker container. you can use containerised chrome or firefox

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Snapd isn't installed properly, and because of that also Chromium

Got that issue some time ago with google-colab as well, the Solution was following:

> Ubuntu 20.04+ no longer distributes `chromium-browser` outside of a `snap` package, you can install a compatible version from the Debian buster repository:
>
> ```bash
> %%shell
> # Ubuntu no longer distributes chromium-browser outside of snap
> #
> # Proposed solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/how-to-install-chromium-without-snap
>
> # Add debian buster
> cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list <<'EOF'
> deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
> deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster-updates.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
> deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-security-buster.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
> EOF
>
> # Add keys
> apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DCC9EFBF77E11517
> apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 648ACFD622F3D138
> apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 112695A0E562B32A
>
> apt-key export 77E11517 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster.gpg
> apt-key export 22F3D138 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster-updates.gpg
> apt-key export E562B32A | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-security-buster.gpg
>
> # Prefer debian repo for chromium* packages only
> # Note the double-blank lines between entries
> cat > /etc/apt/preferences.d/chromium.pref << 'EOF'
> Package: *
> Pin: release a=eoan
> Pin-Priority: 500
>
>
> Package: *
> Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
> Pin-Priority: 300
>
>
> Package: chromium*
> Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
> Pin-Priority: 700
> EOF
>
> # Install chromium and chromium-driver
> apt-get update
> apt-get install chromium chromium-driver
>
> # Install selenium
> pip install selenium
> ```
>
> Example script:
>
> ```py
> from selenium import webdriver
> from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
>
> options = Options()
> options.add_argument("--headless") # or use pyvirtualdiplay
> options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") # needed, because colab runs as root
>
> options.headless = True
>
> driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver", options=options)
>
> driver.get("https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles")
> print(driver.title)
> driver.quit()
> ```
>
> resource: [googlecolab/colabtools#3347 (comment)](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3347#issuecomment-1387453484)
>
> ##### See [Google-Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles/blob/master/google-colab/selenium_profiles.ipynb) (file: google-colab/selenium_profiles.ipynb) for an example

[resource](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles/issues/10)

Disclosure: I am the author of Selenium-Profiles

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I hadn't installed chromium locally, and once that was done properly from within my .venv virtual environment, everything worked properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).